# Android: SQLite update Single value in a col. and then all other of the same col

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the below table in my DB

```
id         name         is_current

1          apple           0
2          banana          1
3          mango           0
4          grapes          1
5          pineapple       1
```

I want to execute an update query which will update the (fruit) table last column (is_current) single value and at the same time the whole column values as well. For example the first row has an apple with `id=1` and I want to set this value to 1 and all other fruit values to zero so the table look like,

```
id         name         is_current

1          apple           1
2          banana          0
3          mango           0
4          grapes          0
5          pineapple       0
```

Currently I am using two different queries and to different methods to achieve this

**1st**: is to set all values of `is_current` column to 0

```
String sql = "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + is_current + " = '"+ Zero +"';
```

**2nd**: is to set the apple values to 1 by using id

```
String sql = "UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME +" SET " + is_current + " = '"+ One +"' WHERE "+ id + " = "+rowId;
```

So how can I combine these two queries to a single one to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`how can I combine these two queries to a single one to achieve this?`

**You can't**.
You have to execute **at least 2 commands**.

A command to update all the `is_current` values to 0.
And a command to update the specified record to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this stuff for a specific fruit/ID (e.g. every time you update apples) you can set a trigger such that when you update that fruit, then it will automatically set to zero all other rows.
However if you want to do this stuff in a more general way then you need to perform 2 queries (as told by @Der Golem)